# Kubernetes ingress rewrite

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I'm currently porting a PHP monolith into Kubernetes, and I'm having some trouble with the URL rewriting in `nginx-ingress`.

The system uses [`phroute`](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute) and that's working all fine. The problem is setting up the nginx ingress to play nice.

The old system had the following rewrite rules:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 1.2.3.4:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$ {
  expires max;
  log_not_found off;
  rewrite "/[a-z0-9]{40}/([^.]+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$" /assets/$1.$2;
}
```

I've tried the following annotations for my nginx ingress:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /index.php?_url=/$1
  hosts:
    - site.kube
  paths: [
    /(.*),
    /[a-z0-9]{40}/([^.]+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$
  ]
```

The below are my questions:

- `phroute` doesn't use the `$_GET['_url']` parameter, but rather `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. How do I set it? If I set the rewrite-target to `/$1`, the routes work, but:
- How do I implement the path for the assets?

Please tell me if I can provide any more information. Thanks.

---

**Edit**

In response to questions in comments, here's some version output.

Kubernetes (latest Minikube, at the time of writing):

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-14T04:24:29Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:09:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

`nginx-ingress` ([built in to minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller)):

```
$ kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-6fc5bcc8c9-qnmz2 -n kube-system
{
    [ ... ]
    Image:         quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.26.1,
    [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: What is your kubernetes version? What is your nginx ingress controller version?

Comment: I found some informations on github about that [FastCGI](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/4344) was added in 0.26.0 on Jul 31. And there is documentation with examples on [kubernetes.github.io](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/fcgi-services/). Let me know if that help you.

Comment: Hi @jt97! Thanks for your response. Sorry for the late reply. I am currently using the latest Minikube for testing. I've added the versions as an edit to the original issue. Great link, I'm currently exploring if it can solve my issue! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, let me know if that help You.

Comment: I have now done what I can with the fast CGI implementation, but I can't get it to work. I get it to enter the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`-section, but that's it. `$request_uri` is never set, assets don't work... I'm at a loss. I just want the original nginx-config to work in the `nginx`-pod, regardless of the ingress. Can you assist me?

Comment: Hi @Helge Talvik Söderström another idea would be to use [snippets](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet), there is some issue on [github](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/458) with it, what You think about creating server-snippets like there in your ingress with location with assets?

Comment: I found it! I'll write up an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

The reason was that the root `server { ... }`-block's `try_files` isn't handled. This has to do with the following line being required to properly propagate the request from the `nginx ingress` to the nginx pod in my deployment, this line is required as an ingress annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

To get it to work, all I did was the following:

1. In my config map for the nginx config, I removed the `try_files` from the `server { ... }`-block.
2. In the `location / { ... }`-block, I changed the `try_files` from:

   ```
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   ```

   to:

   ```
   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
   ```

This solved the problem, because the `rewrite-target` made all requests incoming to nginx end up in the `location / { ... }`-block and thus bypass the server's `try_files`.